# SSIS parameters/variables in destination mapping

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am working on a large SSIS data migration project in which all of the output tables have fields for the creation date & user as well as the last update date and user.  The values will be the same for all of the records in all of the output tables.

Is there a way to define parameters or variables that will appear in the destination mapping window, and can be used to populate the output table?

If I use a sql statement in the source, I could, of course, include extra fields for this, but then I also have to add a Data Conversion task for translating the string fields from varchar to nvarchar.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in the destination mapping.

As you've already considered, you could do this by including the extra fields in the source, but then you are passing all that uniform data through the entire dataflow and perhaps having to convert it as well.

A third option would be to run through your data flow without those columns at all (let them be NULL in the destination), and then follow the data flow with an UPDATE that sets those columns with a package variable value.